# DIVs not positioning as expected

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my self-made console.

I have a picture about what is wrong.
[image: Example]

The `|` is too far out because of the div's width. I don't know how I can fix this.
Any help is appreciated.

My code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="console">
        <div class="console-body">
            <div id="typer"></div><div id="typed-cursor">|</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#262626;
}

.container {
    max-width:800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.console {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: -400px;
    background-color:black;
    width:800px;
    height:400px;
    border:solid 2px #444444;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.console #typer {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
    color:#00FFFF;
    display:inline-block;
}

#typed-cursor{
    font-weight: 100;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

What is wrong?

**FYI: The website is fake and made for educational purposes.**

Comment: Where's website link?

Comment: Can you show us the code running on jsbin, jsfiddle or anywhere please?? With the Inspector Element of browser will be more easy help you!

Comment: Actually I tried to repo your issue, but nope. check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/y4mMD/), maybe some other css might affect.

Comment: Perhaps set `typer` and `typed-cursor` to `display:inline`, or set the width of `typed-cursor` to `5px`.

Comment: @Matthew Baker, can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?
It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inline-block elements to sit next to each other neatly you need to state the elements width.  In this case it may be best for you to set your elements display properties to `display:inline;` This will result in the elements expanding to the size of the content ensuring the *cursor* is tight to the *typer*.

```
.console #typer {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
    color:#00FFFF;
    display:inline;
}


#typed-cursor{
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: 100;
    -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -ms-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -o-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    display:inline;
}
```

Alternatively, you could just set the width of #typed-cursor to 5px (or less).
`width: 5px;`

Answer (score 0):

Add float:left; to the .console #typer CSS

Comment: This doesn't work, the '|' stays on the top line now.